# PCAP Analysis of Youtube

Tags: http, youtube, udp, adb, pcap

I am working on PCAP analysis of youtube to find the time to get first packet before video playback. My works includes capturing Mobile network traffic using adb commands and analyse it in wireshark. Interstingly, I cannot see http traffic when I filter out http but I can see both TCP and UDP protocols. I cannot able to differetiate when get request goes and when the transfer of data is started. But when I see web browser traffic in laptop, it has https and shows when the first video packet arrived. I tried importing pcap log in Fiddler and cannot see https requests. Any help please?